# Programming jquery slider

Tags: jquery, slider

I want to program the jquery slider myself rather than using any plugin.
But i want to know the basic idea.

e.g

I have

```
<ul>
<li>  <div>content </div> </li>
<li>  <div>content </div> </li>
<li>  <div>content </div> </li>
<li>  <div>content </div> </li>
<li>  <div>content </div> </li>

</ul>
```

I want to show horzontally only three items at one time and there will be arroes left and right end.

I know jquery basics. But i don't know how should i do in steps. I mean when click on right arrow

The left div should slide left and new div com right should come left

ANy ideas in sequence what i need to do

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel when jQuery UI Slider is free, easy and works great?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

Comment: Grab the codes from jQuery UI slider, study it to get the idea... (if you really want the idea)  :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you don't want to use a plugin you would be able to learn a lot from looking at the code of one... and you'll probably realise that you're better off just using (or even better contributing to) one of the dozens of existing slider plugins.